# jQuery Function not calling multiple times through php loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a button inside a while loop and then passed a jquery function to it. Now the jquery function is working fine on the first button but doesn't work on other buttons.

```js
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#myBtn").click(function() {
       var id = this.value;
       $("#myModal").modal();
       $("#employee").change(function() {
           var eid = this.value;

           var dataString = 'id=' + id + '&eid=' + eid;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax.php",
               data: dataString,
               success: function(result) {

               }
           });
       });
   });
   });

   /*  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
     var id = this.value;
     if(id == true){alert(id++);}
     
 });
 });*/
</script>
```

```html
   



   <div>
  <div class="panel">
     <table id="basicTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
        <thead class="">
           <tr>
              <th>S.No</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Lead Type</th>
              <th>Customer Name</th>
              <th>Customer Phone No.</th>
              <th>Customer Email</th>
              <th>Property Type</th>
              <th>Property Location</th>
              <th>Active</th>
              <th>Edit</th>
              <th>Assign</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <?php
              $que=mysqli_query($con,"select * from lms_table");
              $number=1;
              while ($res=mysqli_fetch_array($que))
              {
              $id=$res['lead_id'];
              $pt=$res['required_property_type'];
              ?>
           <tr>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $number; ?></td>
              <td align="center"><a href="comment.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $res['title']; ?></a></td>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['lead_type']; ?></td>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['customer_name']; ?></td>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['customer_no']; ?></td>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['customer_email']; ?></td>
              <?php  $qe=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `add_property_type` WHERE property_id='$pt'"); 
                 $re=mysqli_fetch_array($qe); ?>
              <!-- <td align="center"><?php// echo $re['property_type']; ?></td>-->
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['required_property_type']; ?>
              <td align="center"><?php echo $res['property_required_location']; ?></td>
              <?php
                 if($res['lead_status']==1){
                 ?>
              <td align="center"> <a class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Active" href="lead-active.php?l_id='<?php echo $id; ?>'&id=2"><i class="fa fa-user text-success"></i></a></td>
              <?php
                 } else{
                 ?>
              <td align="center"> <a  class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Inactive" href="lead-active.php?l_id='<?php echo $id; ?>'&id=1"><i class="fa fa-user text-danger"></i></a></td>
              <?php  } ?>
              <td align="center"><a href="update-lms-table.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>
              <td align="center"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " name ='but' id="myBtn" value="<?php echo $id['lead_id']; ?>" onclick='get_id(this.value)'>Assign</button> </td>
           </tr>
           <?php 
              $number++; 
              } 
              ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </div>
  <!-- panel -->
   </div>
   <!-- Modal -->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" ?role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
           <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Assign Employee</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
           <form action="half.php">
              <select class="form-control select1 "  id="employee">
                 <option selected value="">Select Employee</option>
                 <?php
                    $que1 =mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_employee");
                    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($que1)){
                            $empid=$r['employee_code']; 
                      echo "<option value='$empid' onchange='get_id(this.value)'>".$r['employee_first_name']."</option>";
                    }                                                      
                    ?>
              </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Login</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
        </form>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

This are the code used. Please shed some light.

Comment: clean your code

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: you can have one name as ID, you must use class if you have multiple buttons and you want onclick event on those.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the callback in the `<options>` tag, add it to the `select` tag. You do not need to attach the callback on every option.

It will work with the select tag alone.

Replace your select tag with this:

```
<select class="form-control select1 " onchange='get_id(this.value)' id="employee">
        <option selected value="">Select Employee</option>
        <?php
            $que1 =mysqli_query($con,"select * from add_employee");
            while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($que1))
            {
                $empid=$r['employee_code'];
                echo "<option value='$empid'>".$r['employee_first_name']."</option>";
            }

                                                ?>
</select>
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: Not it didn't work i got half of the solution as adding a unique number in to id="Mybtn<?php echo $num; ?>" and writing the same script multiple times and passing number 1 2 3 4 5 6 and so on with the $("#myBtn1") and  $("#myBtn2") works. after ten values there is pagination and on 11th button it again dosent works. Thanks for trying.